# If I put <img> in <div> but then erase the contents of the <div> onLoad(), will the browser load the image?

Tags: javascript, html

Running the following code, will the browser ever fetch `bar.png` from the server (whether you see it or not)?

```
<html>
<body onLoad=myLoadFunc()>
<script>
function myLoadFunc() { document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = ""; }
</script>
<div id="foo"> <img src="bar.png"/> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The intention, by the way, is to show bar.png on browsers that don't run the script.

Comment: @pst - you're allowed to edit your question, although I think it was right before.

Comment: @OP If you just want to preload images, you can either use preloading in Javascript (e.g., http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jpreload.htm), or even using only CSS and HTML (http://www.borislavdopudja.net/en/writings/css_preloading/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is wholly adventitious.  The browser is certainly *allowed* to start loading the image before it runs the script -- and I imagine it often will -- but there's nothing like a guarantee either way.

Consider using the `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: Why do you advise use of `<noscript>`? I've read on multiple occasions that it's actually not avisable. (e.g., http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/noscriptnomore.htm)

Comment: I advise *considering* it.  The `<noscript>` tag does exactly what it does.  A lot of people try to use it for things it won't work for (like catching cases where the script *fails* to execute, even though execution is enabled), but that's not really the tag's fault.  I don't know exactly what the OP wants but if it's "load this image when scripting is turned off", that's exactly what `<noscript>` is good for.

Comment: I don't know. Isn't it better to just remove it with JavaScript?

Comment: If that fits the OP's goals, yes.  It sounds like he's trying to keep the image server from being hit in the first place.

Comment: Hm, your are right. In that case, I guess `<noscript>` should work better than any other solution.

Comment: Thanks.  As it happens I'm trying to handle two things at once - `noscript`, and somebody else's widget that fails in some browsers.  Perhaps on reflection I should handle these cases separately, with a `<noscript>` and additional browser detection code.

Comment: @SideshowBob -- that certainly sounds like a good idea.  Very very few people turn off JavaScript nowadays (almost nothing will work).  If Javascript does run, it can certainly look around and see what else ran.